# How can I boot Dell Vista box headless without a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, headless

I have a Dell box running Vista I connect to via RDT.  I'd like to run it completely headless, but it requires a keyboard plugged in or I get the ironic message "No keyboard detected, press F1 to continue".

How can I disable the requirement for there to be a physical keyboard at boot time?

Answer (score 8):

There should be an option in the BIOS to disable a stop on keyboard error.  I don't have a link for you, but that's where I would start.

Comment: I looked in the BIOS but didn't see anything obvious.. I'll look again.

Comment: It'll say something like, "halt on all errors, halt on ram errors, halt on no errors"